# Finetune SavedModel Failure due to No Gradient loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Update: See my own answer to this question. This is a bug of tensorflow Efficientnet**

**WHAT I WANT TO**
I want to finetune efficientnet. First, I successfully finished training and saved a model. It consists of a frozen efficientnet, and fully connected layer. I used `SavedModel` format to save it(See train.py). Then, at the finetuning stage (See finetune.py), I tried to load `SavedModel` , but failed to load.

**PROBLEM**
I couldn't load and retrain `SavedModel` containing Efficientnet successfully.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I tried to `load_model` and `load_weights`, but either didn't help. Does anyone know how to do it?  GradientTape doesn't go with SavedMmodel?. Should I use something else than `load_model` or `load_weights`?

**ENVIRONMENT**
macOS: 10.15.6
Tensorflow==2.3.1

**LOG OUTPUT**

```
... (a very long line of something like this below)

WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_my_model_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_3683150) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.
ail if a gradient is requested.
WARNING:tensorflow:Importing a function (__inference_my_model_layer_call_and_return_conditional_losses_3683150) with ops with custom gradients. Will likely fail if a gradient is requested.

...

File "finetune.py", line 90, in <module>
    _train_loss = train_step(train_images, train_labels).numpy()
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 823, in _call
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 697, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2855, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3213, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 3075, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 986, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 600, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 973, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
tensorflow.python.autograph.impl.api.StagingError: in user code:

    finetune.py:54 train_step  *
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/backprop.py:1073 gradient  **
        unconnected_gradients=unconnected_gradients)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/imperative_grad.py:77 imperative_grad
        compat.as_str(unconnected_gradients.value))
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:797 _backward_function
        return self._rewrite_forward_and_call_backward(call_op, *args)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:712 _rewrite_forward_and_call_backward
        forward_function, backwards_function = self.forward_backward(len(doutputs))
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:621 forward_backward
        forward, backward = self._construct_forward_backward(num_doutputs)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:669 _construct_forward_backward
        func_graph=backwards_graph)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:986 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:659 _backprop_function
        src_graph=self._func_graph)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:669 _GradientsHelper
        lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:336 _MaybeCompile
        return grad_fn()  # Exit early
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:669 <lambda>
        lambda: grad_fn(op, *out_grads))
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:712 _rewrite_forward_and_call_backward
        forward_function, backwards_function = self.forward_backward(len(doutputs))
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:621 forward_backward
        forward, backward = self._construct_forward_backward(num_doutputs)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:669 _construct_forward_backward
        func_graph=backwards_graph)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py:986 func_graph_from_py_func
        func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:659 _backprop_function
        src_graph=self._func_graph)
    /Users/a/my_awesome_project/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_util.py:623 _GradientsHelper
        (op.name, op.type))

    LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'efficientnetb0/top_activation/IdentityN' (op type: IdentityN)
```

**SOURCE CODE**

train.py

```py
import datetime
import os

import tensorflow as tf

from myutils import decode_jpg # defined in another module

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
        input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet')
    self.base_model.trainable = False  # unfreeze at finetuning stage later
    self.global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    self.prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.base_model(x)
    x = self.global_average_layer(x)
    x = self.prediction_layer(x)
    return x

model = MyModel()

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    predictions = model(images, training=True)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./data/*/*.jpg').batch(128).map(decode_jpg)

for epoch in range(100):
  for images, labels in data:
    train_step(images, labels).
  model.save('saved_models/{}'.format(epoch + 1))
```

finetune.py (I refactored for minimized reproduction, so the line number in error log doesn't match)

```py
import datetime
import os

import tensorflow as tf


class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0(
        input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
        include_top=False,
        weights='imagenet'
    )
    self.base_model.trainable = True
    self.global_average_layer = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()
    self.prediction_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(200)

  def call(self, x):
    x = self.base_model(x)
    x = self.global_average_layer(x)
    x = self.prediction_layer(x)
    return x
  
# model = MyModel()
# model.load_weights('./saved_models/65') ValueError: Unable to load weights saved in HDF5 format into a subclassed Model which has not created its variables yet. Call the Model first, then load the weights.
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_models/65') # This way ends up error message above
model.get_layer('efficientnetb0').trainable = True


loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-5)

train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
train_accuracy = tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy(name='train_accuracy')

@tf.function
def train_step(images, labels):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # training=True is only needed if there are layers with different
    # behavior during training versus inference (e.g. Dropout).
    predictions = model(images, training=True)
    loss = loss_object(labels, predictions)
  gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
  optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

EPOCHS = 100
data = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('./data/*/*.jpg').batch(128).map(decode_jpg)
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
  for images, labels in data:
    train_step(train_images, train_labels)
  model.save('finetuned/{}'.format(epoch + 1))
```

I tried to reproduce on Colab but saw a different error message
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gzOwSWJ1Kvwzo01SEpjqGq6Lb-OsI-ob?usp=sharing

Now I made an issue on tensorflow/tensorflow repository.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43806

Comment: This is related to EfficientNet as replacing with ResNet50 doesn't show an error

Answer (score 3):

I answer to my own question. This is EfficientNet bug. Keep eyes on this issue:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/40166